# Mouse down in Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, mouseevent, mouseenter

I'm working on a project in Silverlight. This is the problem:

When mouse enters in my control, I want to check whether the mouse button is down already or not. There is no way to see when it's been pressed because it might have pressed outside of the browser.

Comment: Why are you checking if mouse pressed outside? What is your requirement?

Comment: I can offer javascript but its not a good way,you need to speak with js then. Silverlight is a plugin and generally users know that. Why do you need, I really wonder.

Answer (score 0):

This is a default behavior, thats why mousebuttonup event is used for final actions of your process such as clicking on button does not process its assignment if you release your button outside of the button.

However, you can find a workaround using drag drop features of Silverlight according to your scenario.